# How to show that our model is close to Einstein's gravity after inflation

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, modified-gravity

We have a modified $f \left( R \right)$ gravity model. How can we show that the proposed model is close to Einstein's gravity after inflation and does not contradict observation data?

Comment: Do a literature review of observational constraints. I found [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0102423) quite old paper, but I'm sure if you read a few like it you'll get a feel for how to test your choice of $f$ empirically.